# How to implement timer in a multiplayerchess game? Asp .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, timeout, multiplayer

This is what I currently have: A singleton class `GameManager` which mostly consists of a `ConcurrentDictionary` that contains all ongoing games (binds the game board and nicks of both players to the game's ID). I also have a SignalR hub, `GameHub` with a method `MakeAMove(ulong gameId, Move move)` that retrieves the relevant `gameId` game from the dictionary, `lock`s on it, checks if the player who has invoked the method is the player who is now supposed to make a move and if yes, makes appropriate changes to the game's board, broadcasts this move to all observers of this game and if necessary, concludes the game, declaring it to be a victory of player X or a draw and removing it from the dictionary.

What I don't have is the timer. I think the timer is necessary, because without it many games may never conclude and forever linger in this dict. The timer should work in such a way that if a player fails to make a move within the allocated time, the game is automatically concluded and such a player is declared to be the loser.

I don't know how should such a timer be implemented. I have a few ideas, but I'm not sure which one is correct, if any.

The only idea I have to solve this task that doesn't seem to be horrible to me would look like this: `ConcurrentDictionary` binds `gameId`s to instances of `Game` class. Then each such instance has a method that `await`s until the timer for the player who is supposed to make a move runs out or until `GameHub` notifies this method that a move order has been made, whichever happens first. However, I am ignorant how to implement this.

Is this the right way to go? If yes, then how am I supposed to make this method wait until the timer runs out or until a move order comes to `GameHub`?

EDIT: I SUPPOSE I should write something like this:

```
await Task.WhenAny(
    Task.Delay(players_available_time_left),  
    ??something_to_mean_a_move_order_has_arrived??
);
```

- is this correct? If yes, what should I write instead of the question marks?

Comment: Sounds simpler to have a housekeeping task that does a sweep of the active games, and terminates any which have timed out. How long will the wait time be? A minute? An hour? A day?

Comment: @stuartd Each player gets anywhere in between of 20 sec and 3 mins for each move. Closer to 20 sec if they were thinking for a long time during the previous few moves, closer to 3 mins if they made the previous few moves almost instantly.

Comment: Ah OK. Maybe the task isn't the best solution then - I read _"I think the timer is necessary, because without it many games may never conclude and forever linger in this dict."_ as you were looking to clean-up, rather than implement a game clock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a timer that you start every turn and stop after move is done :

```
private System.Timers.Timer Timer = null;
private double TimerDelay = 30d * 1000d; // 30 seconds
private void StartTimer()
{
    Timer = new System.Timers.Timer() { Interval = TimerDelay , AutoReset = false};
    Timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
    Timer.Start();
} 

private void StopTimer()
{
    Timer.Stop();
}     

private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // stop the timer
    StopTimer();

    // call the method to make the player lose and end the game
    EndGame();                
}
```

When you start the player turn call the `StartTimer()` and let it go. When the player ends it's turn call the `StopTimer()` and it will stop the timer from calling the end of the game. If the timer runs out it will automatically call your end of game.