# How to use a database context in a singleton service?

Tags: asp.net-core, singleton, entity-framework-core

I would like to store completed chess games in the database to support users watching replays.

So far I have a singleton `GameManager` that stores all ongoing games. So within `startup.cs` I have the following line of code:

```
services.AddSingleton<IBattleManager, BattleManager>();
```

Now I would like to have `BattleManager` access the `DbContext` to save completed games.

```
public class BattleManager : IBattleManager
{
    //...
    private void EndGame(ulong gameId)
    {
        var DbContext = WhatDoIPutHere?
        lock(gameDictionary[gameId])
        {
            DbContext.Replays.Add(new ReplayModel(gameDictionary[gameId]));
            gameDictionary.Remove(gameId)
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to anyhow achieve this? How?

Failed attempts:

```
public class BattleManager : IBattleManager
{
    Data.ApplicationDbContext _context;
    public BattleManager(Data.ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

This will clearly fail since one cannot inject EF Core `DbContext` into a Singleton service like that.

I have a vague feeling that I should do something of this kind:

```
using (var scope = WhatDoIPutHere.CreateScope())
{
    var DbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
    DbContext.Replays.Add(new ReplayModel(...));
}
```

Is this the right direction?

Comment: Normally, DbContext is registered as Scope. Why do you want to register as Singleton?

Comment: @Win I know DbContext is registered as Scope. I dont want to register it as Singleton. However, I need a Singleton (GameManager) to write stuff to the database. Is it possible at all? My thinking is that I need to somehow CreateScope in a method of GameManager so that DbContext can safely reside there without violating its Scopeness.

Comment: Or can Singletons never access the database, period, full stop, because we may not, should not use Scoped services inside Singletons in any way?

Comment: Perhaps you should ask yourself why you think you need a Singleton `IBattleManager`.  What do you gain from this?  Why can't multiple instances of it exist?  If you make it Scope does it break anything?

Comment: @Brad 1) The BattleManager needs to remember all turns prior to the turn it is currently processing. I thought since it needs to persistently remember all ongoing games it should be a singleton. 2) The battle manager is not called by razor pages, but rather by a SignalR Hub.

Comment: "A service should only use dependencies with a lifetime longer than or equal to the lifetime of the service"  -- ASP.NET Core In Actoin  .        why not create a new scoped service  that has dependencies to IBattleManager and DbContext ?

Comment: @itminus Or even simpler, I could simply make the SignalR Hub depend on the DbContext. But the problem is, the game ends not only when a player makes a move (eg checkmating the opponent). The game, of course, also ends when a player runs out of time. So the Singleton `IBattleManager` (or more precisely, `BattleState` that `BattleManager` holds in its `gameDictionary`) has instances of `System.Timers.Timer` which, in turn, call `BattleManager.EndGame`. If I create a new scoped service, then this timer must call this new scoped service, so we're back to the original problem.

Comment: @itminus Don't get me wrong, I don't say that your advice is wrong. Very possibly what you say is the best thing to do; only I don't see how can I do this.Clearly, my knowledge of this whole framework AND my knowledge of important design patterns is unsatisfactory yet :(

Comment: @gaazkam I see . I'm wondering , in that case , whether it's possible to move the EndGame to a background task ? I mean , a background task can create scoped services and consume them safely . see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.1#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task

Comment: @itminus hmm interesting, thank you for the link. Though [I was alredy told](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50860400/how-to-implement-timer-in-a-multiplayerchess-game-asp-net-core#comment88724343_50860400) that a task was not the best solution for this job. Not sure what should I do

Comment: @gaazkam , it might not be the best solution to use a background service to do some clean-up  . However , if you don't want to introduce a hosted service , how can you make sure the detection is triggered every 20 secs or 3 mins ?

Comment: @itminus Not every 20 secs or 3 mins. But rather, 20 secs after a player made their move. My current implementation does this: Whenever a player makes a move, the SigalR hub calls a method on BattleManager, which extract the appropriate BattleState, which stops its timer from the previous turn, handles the move and if the game is not over yet, sets the timer again to 20 sec or 3 mins or anything in between; This timer then, if not stopped prematurely, calls an appropriate method on this BattleState which in turn calls BattleManager.EndGame.(...)

Comment: @itminus (...) THis means there are likely as many timers running as are ongoing games. This seems to work, but as I said, I don't insist on keeping this implementation. Still, I am unsure how could I use a background task to do this - my understanding is that I'd have to lock an object on this background task each time any player on any game makes a move, which defeats the pararell nature of the framework?

Comment: @gaazkam Maybe Too many timers  is not a good option . At least it will take  a lot of memory and CPU times . A better way is to store a `Player.LastActiveTime` somewhere in memory or database . A `HeartBeatController` or SignalR hub will refresh the `LastActiveTime` when a player moves  . A hosted service , i.e.  a background task,  will be executed every 20 secs ,  selecting the players whose LastActiveTime >20 secs , doing some cleanup.

Comment: @itminus  OK, Thank you. I think I'll try to do this. The only problem I see with this is that this seems to forfeit the accuracy of the timers. Assume a player's time runs out 1 sec after the last cleanup: then we will have to wait 19 more secs for the game to conclude. This seems to be a minor problem, since we can check `LastActiveTime` when a player orders a move (so no spurious time is allocated), however this may be mildly annoying for the winner, who will have to wait up to 20sec for the game to conclude.

Comment: @gaazkam the winner does not have to wait 20 secs . Every time a player moves , the server should check the rules  . When you can conclude who is the winner  , just update a flag in database and notify the client . If you feel like to EndGame immediately , you can inject a scoped-service to do that . Since your EndGame method only has dependencies on DbContext (which is a scoped service )and gameDictionary (which seems like a singleton service) .

Comment: @itminus Yes but what when the game concludes because a player runs out of time? THEN it may take up to 20 sec to actually conclude the game because the timers are only checked every 20 sec?

Comment: @gaazkam they are two situations . When a player moves , if a game manager can conclude that someone loses , just end the game by a scoped service ; or else , refresh the LastActiveTime . If someone runs out of time , the background service will take care of that case .  By the way , there's a bug in your original implementation .  "Whenever a player makes a move, the SigalR hub calls a method on BattleManager, "  so what will happen if someone kills the client process or disconnects from network  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178524/discussion-between-itminus-and-gaazkam).

Answer (score 13):

You're on the right track. The [`IServiceScopeFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.iservicescopefactory?view=aspnetcore-2.1) can do that.

```
public class BattleManager : IBattleManager {

    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory;

    public BattleManager(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
    {
        this.scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
    }

    public void MyMethod() {
        using(var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope()) 
        {
            var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DbContext>();

            // when we exit the using block,
            // the IServiceScope will dispose itself 
            // and dispose all of the services that it resolved.
        }
    }
}
```

The `DbContext` will behave like it has a `Transient` scope within that `using` statement.

Comment: This is where I ended up as well but many people say injecting the service provider is an anti-pattern.  I'm exactly sure why, but this seems like a common issue where a service is running in the background and needs to talk to a database (DbContext).  I wonder if there is any additional guidance on how to handle this common scenario without making a DbContext a singleton and avoiding antipattern by injecting service provider interfaces.

Comment: I think people get too hung up on injecting the `IServiceProvider` being an anti-pattern. Their reasoning being that if you change your DI container, then you have swap it out with whatever the container provides. Frankly, at the end of the day, you need to solve a problem and have working code and taking a dependency that's considered "anti-pattern" seems like the tiniest of worries. Besides, if you're swapping out DI containers, you're probably going to be doing a decent amount of bug fixes here and there until it works completely anyway. I say don't worry about it. I didn't.